# C++ automatic finalization or objects destruction

Tags: c++, stl, raii, code-structure, finalization

In this example I faced the problem of copying the code:

```
void BadExample1() {
  if (!Initialize1())
    return;

  if (!Initialize2())  {
    Finalize1();
    return;
  }

  if (!Initialize3())  {
    Finalize1();
    Finalize2();
    return;
  }

  if (!Initialize4()) {
    Finalize1();
    Finalize2();
    Finalize3();
    return;
  }

  // some code..

  Finalize1();
  Finalize2();
  Finalize3();
  Finalize4();
}
```

Bnd here is a bad code structure. If I have a lot of constructs, the width of the code will be too large, this is also bad:

```
void BadExample2() {
  if (Initialize1()) {
    if (Initialize2()) {
      if (Initialize3()) {
        if (Initialize4()) {
          if (Initialize5()) {
            // some code..

            Finalize5();
          }
          Finalize4();
        }
        Finalize3();
      }
      Finalize2();
    }
    Finalize1();
  }
}
```

How can I save good code sturcture and solve code copying?
Finalize1/2/3 is a API functions and not my program classes.
Maybe some STL containers can solve it?
Maybe something like that?

```
void GoodExample() {
  if (!Initialize1())
    return;
  RaiiWrapper<void(*)()> raii_wrapper1([]() {
    Finalize1();
  });

  if (!Initialize2())  {
    //Finalize1();
    return;
  }
  RaiiWrapper<void(*)()> raii_wrapper2([]() {
    Finalize2();
  });

  if (!Initialize3())  {
    //Finalize1();
    //Finalize2();
    return;
  }
  RaiiWrapper<void(*)()> raii_wrapper3([]() {
    Finalize3();
  });

  if (!Initialize4()) {
    //Finalize1();
    //Finalize2();
    //Finalize3();
    return;
  }
  RaiiWrapper<void(*)()> raii_wrapper4([]() {
    Finalize4();
  });

  // some code..

  //Finalize1();
  //Finalize2();
  //Finalize3();
  //Finalize4();
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how you solve it. Classes like `RaiiWrapper` are called *scope guards*. They are not in the standard library, but implementing them isn't hard either.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use real objects?

```
struct SetupPart1 {
   SetupPart1  () { if (!Initialize1() throw std::runtime_error("Part1"); }
   ~SetupPart1 () { Finalize1(); }
};
```

and so on for part 2, 3, 4, etc.
Now your example looks like this:

```
void GoodExample() {
    try {
        SetupPart1 p1;
        SetupPart2 p2;
        SetupPart3 p3;
        SetupPart4 p4;

     // some code ...
        }
    catch { const std::runtime_error &ex ) {
        std::cerr << "GoodExample Failed: " << ex.what << std::end;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could streamline Marshall's suggestion and use the not-yet-standardized [`std::make_unique_resource()`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4189.pdf) (this function is closely related to `scope_guard`, a contraption suggested by Andrei Alexandrescu some years ago and also in that proposal). That gives you an object with two functions - one to run at the variable scope's start, another to run at its end (i.e. on construction and destruction respectively).

Then, instead of defining four separate classes, you'd just write:

```
void GoodExample() {
    auto r1 = std::make_unique_resource(Initialize1, Finalize1);
    auto r2 = std::make_unique_resource(Initialize2, Finalize2);
    auto r3 = std::make_unique_resource(Initialize3, Finalize3);
    auto r4 = std::make_unique_resource(Initialize4, Finalize4);

    // some code
}
```

The proposal has code for the implementation; and - it's not complex at all. So you could just copy the implementation and create your own `not_std::make_unique_resource()` function and related templated class(es).

Comment: Technically not useful until it is standardized, but still worth an upvote.

Comment: @user4581301: It _is_ useful - one could just the implementation in the proposal, which is not even that long. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get a precious resource from an API, you need to wrap it as an object with the appropriate destructor.  So, if `Initialize1` initialises `something1` then `something1` should really be an object `Something1` that knows how to initialise and how to finalise itself.  Also, a failure to initialise should throw an exception (this is not done with `fstream` because `fstream` is older than this concept).

```cpp
class Something1 {
public: Something1 () { if (!Initialize1()) throw resource_failed ("1"); }
~Something1 () { Finalize1(); }
}
```